# CakePHP 3.0 database modification

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I baked a new CakePHP app few days ago, I made the [Bookmarker Example](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html).

And in that example, the SQL script shows that the tables `users`, `bookmarks` and `tags` have each 2 fields named `created` and `updated`.
So I ran this script in the MySQL database.

But this morning I realized that the field `updated` was empty in all my entries.
After a little search, I found out that the field had to be named `modified` instead of `updated` to be filled by CakePHP.

My question is : now that I already baked my app, with all models, tables, and controllers, I would like to change `updated` into `modified`, do I have to "re-bake" my tables ?

Comment: No just change the table structure and remember to `debug` mode to be set to `2` and for assurance clear `model` cache from temp folder.

Comment: In CakePHP 3.0, isn't the `debug` mode `true` or `false` ?

Comment: Yes it is my mistake, missed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it. No need to re-bake, I just renamed the fields `updated` in `modified` in each table on phpmyadmin, and then changed :

`<th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('updated') ?></th>`
into
`<th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('modified','Updated') ?></th>  //sort([field],[label])`

and

`<td><?= h($bookmark->updated) ?></td>  //in that case, it was Bookmarks/index.ctp`
into
`<td><?= h($bookmark->modified) ?></td>`

in the index.ctp of `Bookmarks`, `Users`, and `Tags`.

---

Also :

`<p><?= h($bookmark->updated) ?></p>`
into
`<p><?= h($bookmark->modified) ?></p>`

and

`<td><?= h($tags->updated) ?></td>`
into
`<td><?= h($tags->modified) ?></td>`

in the view.ctp of the 3 tables.

---

It now works well, Cake fills out the `modified` field when I update it.